# Beginner in iPad App Development

Tags: ipad, xcode4

I'm a beginner in ipad app development.I've been given an app to develop like the image shown! Both the table views change when the buttons are tapped.I tried using split view but it occupies the whole screen. I just wanted to know the best way to go about this. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found this book very useful for the beginner. I recommend you should buy and read the book, it has some sample that is almost as per your requirement. And a piece of advice, that not just complete the task but to learn whats the basic for the iPad Development.

Here is the link: [iPhone and iPad Apps for Absolute Beginners](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430227001)

Happy coding with iPad and iPhone :)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new Master-Detail application. It should do that basic layout automatically.

Hope it helps

Comment: Master-Detail as in Splitview?

Comment: sorry, didn't see that there should be a background image. Have you tried adding the table views manually? You should be able to set their frames that way.

Comment: @Thiba it might be. I've never created an iPad application like that. But you can also try to create a new Master-Detail application and then copy-paste the code that it uses to your project. Just change the frames and other things that you need to change.